# How to speed up this python loop script or parallelize it

Tags: performance, parallel-processing

I am currently working on a script which takes in data for a correlation matrix and compute a bunch of values. this step right here is very costly, and I would like to find ways to speed it up or parallelize it. I have tried using Parallel (from python's joblib) however because of CPU overhead (at least because of the way I parametrized it) it's significantly slower than a sequential loop.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import itertools
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs


N = 5000
data,_ = make_blobs(n_samples=N,n_features=500)
G =  np.corrcoef(data)


''' the cluster function '''
def clus_lc(i, j, G, ns=2):
    ''' c_s'''
    cs = 2*(G[i,j]+1)-1e-6
    ''' A and B'''
    if cs<=ns:
        return 0
    return 0.5*( np.log(ns/cs) +  (ns - 1)*np.log( (ns**2 - ns) / ( ns**2 - cs) )  )

''' merge and time '''


indices = list(itertools.combinations(range(N),2))
t0 = time.time()
costs = np.zeros(len(indices))
k=0
for i, j in indices:
    costs[k] = clus_lc(i,j,G)
    k+=1
t1 = time.time()
toseq = t1-t0
print(toseq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the issue by using numba and adding a decorator @jit. This seems to work fine because all operations in the function are calls to numpy functions. On a dataset with N=5000 it goes from 75 sec to 10 sec. Fantastic improvement. Now whether this can be further improved I am interested in hearing other inputs.